# What are the long-term side effects of betamethasone valerate medicated plasters used to treat a tendinopathy?

Tags: tendinopathy, epicondylitis, patches

What are the long-term effects of betamethasone valerate medicated plasters used to treat a tendinopathy? I am mostly interested in treatment effectiveness as well as the long-term impact on the tendon and its surroundings. I am mostly interested in epicondylitis (epicondylopathy).

(1) gives some encouraging results but only look at short term outcomes (28 days):

> OBJECTIVE: to investigate the efficacy and safety of a medicated
>   plaster containing betamethasone valerate (BMV) 2.25 mg in patients
>   with chronic elbow tendinopathy.
>
> METHODS: randomized, double-blind, placebo-controlled study with
>   assignment 2:2:1:1 to BMV medicated plaster applied daily for 12
>   hours, daily for 24 hours or matched placebo. 62 patients aged ≥18
>   years with chronic lateral elbow tendinopathy were randomized. The
>   primary efficacy variable was pain reduction (VAS) at day 28.
>   Secondary objectives included summed pain intensity differences
>   (SPID), overall treatment efficacy and tolerability.
>
> RESULTS: **mean reduction in VAS pain score at day 28 was greater in
>   both BMV medicated plaster groups**, -39.35±27.69 mm for BMV12-h and
>   -36.91±32.50 mm for BMV24-h, than with placebo, -20.20±27.32 mm. Considering the adjusted mean decreases, there was a statistically
>   significant difference between BMV12-h and placebo (p=0.0110). Global
>   pain relief (SPID) and overall treatment efficacy were significantly
>   better with BMV. BMV and placebo plasters had similar local
>   tolerability and there were few treatment-related adverse events.
>
> CONCLUSIONS: BMV plaster was significantly more effective than placebo
>   at reducing pain in patients with chronic elbow tendinopathies. The
>   BMV plaster was safe and well tolerated.

---

- (1) Frizziero, Antonio, Araldo Causero, Stefano Bernasconi, Rocco Papalia, Mario Longo, Vincenzo Sessa, Francesco Sadile et al. "Efficacy of betamethasone valerate medicated plaster on painful chronic elbow tendinopathy: a double-blind, randomized, placebo-controlled trial." Muscles, Ligaments and Tendons Journal 6, no. 1 (2016): 131. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27331041

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.